# GADBannerView doesn't show ads

Tags: ios, swift, admob

```
var ad1 = GADBannerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   ...

   ad1.unitID = "MyUnitID"
   ad1.rootViewController = self
   let request = GADRequest()
   //request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID ]
   ad1.load(request)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   if indexPath.row == 0 {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pubblicita", for: indexPath)
      ad1.frame = cell.contentView.frame
      cell.contentView.addSubview(ad1)
      return cell
   }
   else {
      ...
   }
}
```

The problem is that if I add the test devices it works and shows me the test ad banner, but if I don't the banner view doesn't show anything.
I double checked the banner id.
Where is the error?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I recall reading that, while testing your app in your test devices (or inside the simulator), you can only test the ad banners. In order to get them work with normal devices, you need to actually distribute your app in the App Store.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll search if that is the case.